# make wordpress to use the current page template when click a menu item which is a category

Tags: wordpress, templates

I created a page template for students page (its slug is *student*). in this page there is a vertical menu in the right sidebar of the page. menu items have been selected from categories, pages, post types etc. when I click on a menu item that is a category, then, wordpress will load category.php template, while I want to open that link in the student page template (current page) not in category template. meanwhile, If the user clicks on every menu item, then, the results were shown in the current page not another templates .
I don't know how to control that.

thanks for your reply and help.

Comment: page template of student is to show posts of custom post type ?

Comment: dear Qamar, student page has a menu. each <li> tag of the menu shows something based on its type. for example if it is a category item , wordpress will   automatically open category.php template, and also if it is a page wordpress will open page.php template to show the result. But I want if user click on each <li> tag wordpress load the result based on page-student.php template( in the current page). thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The template for displaying all your posts should not be a custom page template. You should set the page you want to use as your Posts page in Settings > Reading. Then, as per the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), your theme will automatically use home.php for this page, or index.php if that does not exist.

So you should save your template as home.php, without the /* Template Name: Blog Template */ comment, and set the page you want to use for displaying posts in Settings > Reading.

Comment: dear valleria, thanks for your reply. this page is not my site font-page and is one of internal pages in my website.